# Loopback: Unknown column 'realm' in 'field list'"

Tags: loopbackjs

I have been stuck with LoopBack for the last couple of hours trying to extend the User model with a custom model called Client.

```
{
  "name": "Client",
  "base": "User",
  "plural": "Clients",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "mysql": {
      "schema": "LOOPBACK",
      "table": "my_table_name"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

After doing the autoupdate I am not seeing any other properties in the client table than "test". 
From the explorer I try to submit a new user, but I get the following error:

```
 "uniqueness.Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'realm' in 'field list'"
```

Read every possible answer on google, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually create a column called 'realm' on your table 'my_table_name' and check if it fixes.

Comment: well yes, but than another column would need to be added for username and password until the entire user table is duplicated. not a very nice architectural solution.

Comment: I was thinking about a quickfix :) You can try to use PersistedModel as base and then create a hook into your Client class that calls to User.create()

Comment: @apfz How you resolved this issue. I am also getting the same issue , i used automigration where i am able to insert the user table into mysql and able to login and getting the access token,that access token , i am setting in the explorer but when i am fetching the request from the another model which i extended to User class throwing the same error like you

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude properties present in User but absent in your Model. My extended user has this property right before "properties" property:

```
"excludeBaseProperties": [
    "realm",
    "password",
    "emailVerified",
    "verificationToken"
  ],
```